# open braintree login screen as an iframe in ruby on rails

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, iframe

I am using an https website,

In my `index.html.halm` i have a link like this `braintree`

When i click onto this link i will be redirected to the page `braintree.html.erb` , From here i want to open an iframe for login into the braintree , exactly this page 
[braintree](https://www.braintreepayments.com/signin)

I can easily do this if i am trying to open an http page for example `http://rubyonrails.org/`

How can i open this braintree as an iframe .

I have tried this below code so far,

**index.html.halm**

```
= link_to "braintree/index?url=https://www.braintreepayments.com/signin" braintree
```

**my_controller.rb**

```
def index
    @url = params[:url]
  end
```

**braintree.html.erb**

```
<iframe src="<%= @url %>
```

Comment: They may be blocking that request.  I have seen things before where sites block opening in an iframe.

Comment: is there any solution for this?